# MVC: please identify the accessibility correctly among MVC layers

Tags: model-view-controller

I was learning MVC web development in php for last few weeks and got confused over several online article with different interpretations.
Please help me to identify the correct accessibility from the following list:

[T = True, F=False, Here access means access to layer data & functions]

1. Model can access View = T/F
2. View can access Model = T/F
3. Model can access Controller = T/F
4. Controller can access Model = T/F
5. View can access Controller = T/F
6. Controller can access View = T/F

Please help. thanks

Comment: Here is the [Wikipedia page for MVC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which just so happens to have a diagram that shows you exactly what you want

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: haha. Nope, its my job project. Thanks @arvymetal :)

Answer (score 1):

In traditional MVC, the controller makes the link with the view and the model.
An input event reaches the controller, which calls the model, grab the result, and send it to the view.

So only points 4 and 6 are true.